# Adding notification to app that makes pdfs

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I have an app that creates pdf's for the user. When this app creates a new pdf (say on the users i-pad) I want the iwatch to display a notification saying a new pdf has been created.

Does this require a server, it was my understanding apple could provide this service.

Any help or tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to address the difference between local and push notifications. Local Notifications would be used on the specific device the user is on at the time, and is normally scheduled for a specific time such as the reminder app notifying you at a scheduled time. Push notification are sent via a server to other devices.

Since you want to send to the other devices you will want to implement push notifications. In order to do this the user will need your app on all devices. Additionally you will need to have a login system so you know which devices belong to the same user. From there you will need a push notification service that can do targeted push notifications. There are many services out there and you will need to decide which one is right for your situation.

Push notifications are sent to the device by using the device token Apple provides after the user approves notifications for your app. Each app on each device has their own device token. So in addition to targeted notifications you will want a push service that allows you to setup channels such as parse.com, that way you can setup a channel specific to each user (email, username, or ...). Then when your user logs in on any device and approves getting push notifications, their channel will be set to (whatever option you choose) and you can trigger the push notification to the specific channel and will send the notification to any device.

There are other consideration but this is a good place to start.

Comment: I'm assuming this means there's no way to just send a push notification to everyone who has my app from the same Apple ID?

Comment: The way notifications work is when you install your app the user is prompted if they would like to receive push notifications. If they approve apple assigns a token. That token is your responsibility on how you handle but I don't believe you can prompt a user for their apple id and you can't trigger notifications to an apple id as it has to be sent to a specific device token. You will need to setup your code to handle how it deals with the token for each device. Implementing logins allows you to setup a channel for each user and then trigger the notification to that specific channel.

Comment: One last question, would this still be the case even if the pdf's were being synced through icloud?

Comment: Yes. Push notifications are their own animal/beast/module. They are not tied to an apple id or iCloud account. You will want to save your pdf's to iCloud prior to sending the notification. When the notification is received they can click on it to open your app and based on how your app is setup will be able to see your pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Local notification is just that, local to that device. Remote notification is what you need. You will either need to create a server for this purpose or use one of the variety of third-party services (Urban Airship, Parse, etc) to provide that functionality.

Clarification point -- when you say:

> I want their iphone, and every other device that they have to receive a notification that a new pdf has been created

it is assumed that you mean "every device of theirs that is running your app and has approved notifications from your app". If you're trying to piggy-back on some magic AppleID-related foo, that won't be possible.

Comment: Thank you for your help! And yes your clarification point is correct, I want every device of theirs that has my app and approved notifications to be alerted that a new pdf was just created. A lot of what I've seen with the services you listed is a way to send users a mass message. I just want to notify them that they have created a new pdf. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: It's up to you as a developer to identify which users get what messages; the different services give you different tools to do so (hint: your use case will be tied to something unique about the user to be able to differentiate what devices belong to whom). It's beyond the scope of this answer to describe how you go about it in detail, though. Take a look at the different services and see what they offer. See how you might go about it. If you get stuck, ask for help again but with a much narrower query.

Comment: I will follow the steps you have suggested, thank you!